# Restrict domain object retrieval from database based on a global criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to restrict retrieval of objects based on a global criteria in grails?

Example:
There are objects in the database that have a status deleted. I don't want those objects to be returned when I make a query. For instance `Object.all` should not return objects that are marked as deleted.

I looked at the action listener method `afterLoad()` but could not figure out how it works or if it is the way to go. I also thought about metaprogramming but I don't really want to go that way.

Comment: There are other ways to achieve what you need using, for example, `findAll`, `findAllWhere`, etc. Any specific reason to stick to global criterion?

Comment: @JustmeVSI You can use hibernate filter. For example http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/07/13/grails-hibernate-filter-plugin-a-life-saver/

Comment: You may try hibernate filters to achieve this. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Comment: I would go with named queries, http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html then you can specify for example "deleted = true" and chain that bad boy with other statements.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will go with the named queries. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

marko is on point, namedQueries are the way to go. You could also have a base class that all domain objects inherit from with a property called Deleted which is set when you do whatever it is that causes a 'Delete'. Your find* queries can now say where not Deleted